# Can I get the contents of a s3 static website to my s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a Data analytics project and I have a static website “https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html” where the data is hosted. Is there anyway that I can get the files hosted on the site into my s3 bucket without me downloading the files manually and uploading to my s3 bucket.

Comment: sorry but it’s not clear what you’re trying to achieve. You have already setup the static website in S3? What files would you like to be uploaded and on which bucket?

Comment: Something like `aws s3 sync s3://divvy-tripdata s3://example-bucket/prefix/`, perhaps with `aws configure set default.s3.multipart_threshold 1gb` ?

Comment: @AR1 I am sorry for the confusion, the static website that I mentioned is from a bike rental company. That is not mine.